# Unable to load Hive-JDBC driver when accessed through MapReduce program on Amazon's Elastic MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, mapreduce, hive, elastic-map-reduce

I have written a MapReduce program in which I am storing some part of output data into `Hive` table.

I have used `Hive-JDBC driver` to access `Hive` table via `MapReduce` code.

This program has compiled successfully on local machine.

After this, I created a JAR file and uploaded it on `S3`. Then I created an `elasticmapreduce cluster` and started it.

However, it is resulting into below mentioned errors:

> java.lang.Throwable: Child Error  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271) Caused
>   by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)
>
> **attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver**
>   attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0:     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>   attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0:     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>   attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0:     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0:     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>   attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0:     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>   attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0:     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>   attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0:     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0:     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>   attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0:     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
>   attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0:     at
>   HubAndAuthority.InputHubMapper.configure(InputHubMapper.java:38)
>   attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0:     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0:     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0:     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   attempt_201407161054_0001_m_000001_0:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

It appears to be an issue of missing `Hive-JDBC driver` and it should get resolved by adding `Hive-JDBC driver` in `classpath`. However, I am not aware of the exact step to do this on `Amazon's EMR`.

Could you please let me know what is missing from my end and how to resolve it?

Thanks and Regards,
Prafulla

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure enough, but you should try this:

"Note
If you want your custom classpath to override the original class path, you should set the environment variable, HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST to true so that the HADOOP_CLASSPATH value specified in hadoop-user-env.sh is first."

1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hadoop-config.html
2. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hadoop-config_hadoop-user-env.sh.html

Regards,
revet